# How to join multiple documents in a Cloud Firestore query? - Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Cloud Firestore DB with the following structure:

**users**
**[uid]**
name: "Test User"

**posts**
[id]
content: "Just some test post."
timestamp: (Dec. 22, 2017)
uid: **[uid]**

There is more data present in the actual DB, the above just illustrates the collection/document/field structure.

I have a view in my web app where I'm displaying posts and would like to display the name of the user who posted. I'm using the below query to fetch the posts:

Comment: The query you say attached is not in the post-

Comment: Please add the query.

Comment: Need to include sample data and code. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).